# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS live boot same as install?

Tags: boot, lts

I am planning to buy a cheap pc for school, and was thinking about installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it. I am not sure if it actually works, so I was planning on testing it with a live boot before installing.
My question is: If it works 100% on the live boot, will it still work when installing it on the HDD without much of an hassle? (removing windows 10)

Without too much hassle I mean not doing a ton of work in the terminal and downloading drivers for hours.

The PC is a HP 14-ac102no

Comment: If the live CD works 100% (no problems with internet connection, screen brightness keys, sound, etc.), then this is a good sign. But to be safe, I would dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, first, until you have determined that Ubuntu works well enough on your computer for daily use

Answer (score 0):

If the Live CD works properly, installing Ubuntu will almost definitely give you a working system.

What you can do to be more sure is to resize the Windows partition in Gparted on the Live CD, keeping it around. Install Ubuntu into a new `/` partition and a new swap partition (after the `/` partition) using the space left over. Run Ubuntu for a few days to see if it works.

If it does work, either reinstall Ubuntu by erasing the hard drive and using the whole drive or run Gparted on the Live CD, delete the Windows partition, and resize the Ubuntu partition to take the freed up space as well.

If it doesn't work, run Gparted on the Live CD, delete the Ubuntu partitions, and resize the Windows partition to take up the drive.